# An error when using Tk with Ruby to open files and cancelling

Tags: ruby, tk-toolkit

I'm new to Ruby (and scripting or programming in general) and cannot seem to be able to figure out the source of this error (or annoyance):

So the minimum code to replicate the problem is:

```
require 'tk'

open(Tk.getOpenFile)
```

Now the dialog opens as expected and everything goes fine as long as I select some file. If I press cancel I expected it to quietly close the dialog, but instead it throws all sorts of errors. Is there anything I can do to prevent these error messages?

The error messages I receive are:

```
file_path:in `initialize': No such file or directory -  (Errno::ENOENT)
    from file_path:3:in `open'
    from file_path:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from -e:1:in `load'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

I have to say I don't really understand what's happening. Can someone explain this in an introductory manner (I have googled for quite a while, but (probably due to my limited knowledge and vocabulary in these matters) I haven't found anything that explains this to me). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have written these two instructions (require 'tk' + open) in a script and executed it. I can select a file and open, or close the dialog box, nothing bad happens. The error message you give shows that there are other statements (load, file_path) which can be the cause of the error. Please check what happens with these two statements and give more of the code you are really executing.

Comment: This is what happens when I execute only those two lines of code. It only happens when the 'Cancel' button is pressed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Errno::ENOENT is the operating system error for file not found.

What does Tk.getOpenFile return when canceled? empty string

What is the error message when open is called on empty string? Error::ENOENT

You should probably do something like:

```
file = Tk.getOpenFile
open(file) unless file.empty?
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `Tk.getOpenFile` returns an empty string when you press cancel. You then pass the empty string to the `open` method (it expects a proper file path) and it blows up.

To make the code work in all cases, you just need to check for the empty string.

```
file_path = Tk.getOpenFile
open(file_path) unless file_path.empty?
```